# Filter latest record in Django

Tags: python, django

Writing my first Django app that gets messages from other applications and stores reports about them.

It is performing very slow due to the following logic that I hope can be improved but I'm struggling to find a way to do it with out a loop.

Basically I'm just trying to go through all of the apps (there are about 500 unique ones) and get the latest report for each one.  Here are my models and function:

```
class App(models.Model):
    app_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    host = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Report(models.Model):
    app = models.ForeignKey(App)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    runtime = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=2,blank=True,null=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)



def get_latest_report():
    """ Returns the latest report from each app """
    lset = set()
    ## get distinct app values
    for r in Report.objects.order_by().values_list('app_id').distinct():
        ## get latest report (by date) and push in to stack.
        lreport = Report.objects.filter(app_id=r).latest('date')
        lset.add(lreport.pk)
    ## Filter objects and return the latest runs
    return Report.objects.filter(pk__in = lset)
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not afraid of executing a query for every app in your database you can try it this way:

```
def get_latest_report():
    """ Returns the latest report from each app """
    return [app.report_set.latest('date') for app in App.objects.all()]
```

This adds a query for every app in your database, but is really expressive and sometimes maintainability and readability are more important than performance.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `latest` negates the advantage of using `prefetch_related` as it will create an additional query for every app

Comment: Well your answer is really good, what can I say :) I'll leave it here because it's really expressive, and the performance hit might not matter for many users.

Comment: Your answer is definitely more pythonic than mine!

Comment: Thanks, this returns the same info just about as fast as my method but is much cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PostgreSQL you can use `distinct` and `order_by` in combination, giving you the latest report for each app like so

```
Report.objects.order_by('-date').distinct('app')
```

If you are using a database that does not support the `DISTINCT ON` clause, MySQL for example, and you do not mind changing the default ordering of the `Report` model, you can use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to reduce 500+ queries to 2 (however this method will use a lot more memory as it will load every report)

```
class Report(models.Model):

    # Fields

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']

def get_latest_report():
    latest_reports = []
    for app in App.objects.all().prefetch_related('report_set'):
        try:
            latest_reports.append(app.report_set.all()[0])
        except IndexError:
            pass
    return latest_reports
```

Comment: This method also returns the same info but instead of 10 seconds to run, it takes 30-40 seconds.